# Fliter Point Cloud

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, filter

I want to filter a point cloud. The figure shows the result of the intersection of a sphere with a trapezoid. So basically I only need the points which describe the curved surface. My Idea was to figure out the unique values in X and Y and find the lowest Z value for every possible combination of every unique X and Y value.

A csv file contains the entire point cloud:

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=' ')


uniqueX = data.X.unique()
uniqueY = data.Y.unique()
```

I am not sure how to iterate and combine the uniqueX and unique as a filter method to find the min Z.

Any ideas?

[image: Point Cloud]

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could add sample data to your question, but if you want to find the minimum of z for every combination of x and y, I think you can **use `.groupby()`**:

```
data.groupby(['x', 'y'])['z'].min()
```

**Documentation and examples on the use of `.groupby()`:**

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html